# ¿Como diferenciar los nombres?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, sql-server-2014

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual se guardan los datos de personas, mi pregunta, como puedo hacerle para diferenciar los nombres de las personas, es decir, si ya tengo el nombre "Jose Lopez", como le puedo hacer para que no me deje guardar el nombre si es igual, o poder guardarlo si el apellido cambia, lo he intentado con like, y despues el resultado lo comparo con el valor de un texbox:

consulta like:

```
        DataTable dt = null;
        String query = "SELECT Nombre FROM Empleados WHERE Nombre = '" + Nombre + "'";
        dt = daccess.select(query);
        return dt;
```

comparacion

> ```
>         DataTable NomE = biss.BuscarNombre(txtNombreE.Text);
>         String NombreE = NomE.ToString();
>         if(NombreE == txtNombreE.Text)
>         {
>             biss.IEmple(Convert.ToInt32(txtNumEmp.Text), txtNombreE.Text, txtDirecciionE.Text, mtxtTelefonoE.Text, txtIMSS.Text, txtCURP.Text, txtRFC.Text, txtDatosFamilia.Text.Replace("'\r\'", ","), dtpFechaN.Value.ToShortDateString(), Convert.ToInt32(cbEstadoCivil.SelectedValue), 1);
>             biss.IDNomina(Convert.ToInt32(txtNumEmp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cbTipoE.SelectedValue.ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(cbDepartamentoE.SelectedValue.ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(cbPuestoE.SelectedValue.ToString()), dtpFechaIE.Value.ToShortDateString(), txtContraseñaE.Text, Convert.ToInt32(cbTipoSueldo.SelectedValue.ToString()), Convert.ToDouble(txtSueldo.Text), dtpHoraEntrada.Text, dtpHoraSalida.Text, dtpHoraSS.Text);
>             CajasBlancas();
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             MessageBox.Show("El Empleado Ya Existe");
>             //CajasBlancas();
>         }
> ```

pero si lo dejo asi, cuando quiero por ejemplo guardar jose perez, y ya tengo a alguien llamado jose guardado, no me deja, como le puedo hacer para que me deje guardarlo si el apellido es diferente.

Comment: cual es la consulta "like"? en ese select no veo que uses ningun like, solo devuelves la cantidad de registros de la tabla. Que es lo que intentas hacer con NomE.ToString() ? es un datatable con rows y columns no funciona hacer el ToString()

Comment: Un ejemplo puede ser el RFC, las dos primeras letras del primer apellido + primera letra del segundo apellido + primera letra del primer nombre + dos ultimos digitos del año de nacimiento + dos digitos del mes + dos digitos de dia de nacimiento + homoclave. Donde la homoclave esta compuesta por tres caracteres.

Comment: perdon, me equivoque de consulta, ya lo corregi

Comment: No es buena idea restringir por nombre, pues puede haber 2+ personas con el mismo nombre. Como escribió Tecnologer, debes buscar otro campo para ser tu clave primaria, un buen ejemplo es el RFC, otro campo, aquí en México, la CURP, o tendrías que poner un autoincrementable en tu tabla y que ese sea tu clave primaria.

Comment: ¿Y si agregas un constraint único en tu tabla de la base de datos? así la misma base de datos no permitirá agregar repetidos.

Comment: Los nombres no son unicos. Nunca. Tu clave debe ser un autonumerico o algun tipo de numero que incrementes vos. Pero ningun dato de la persona debe ser la clave.

Comment: si bien es cierto que un nombre no es un valor único, puedes hacer splits del textbox, y dando por hecho que el primero es el nombre, ya lo tienes en la primera posicion del array y es lo que tendrás que enviar a la consulta SQL. Que por cierto, la consulta SQL ha de ser `"WHERE nombre like " + Nombre +"%"`

Comment: No se confundan, cada persona registrada tiene un id único, pero las búsquedas yo las ocupo hacer por el nombre de las personas, aquí mi pregunta fue como detectar si un nombre que inserto es igual a uno que ya tengo guardado

Comment: @gbianchi Depende mucho de cómo estás usando tu tabla, los nombres si pueden ser únicos si tu regla de negocio así lo dicta.

Comment: En el 99% de lps casos. Si son nombres de personas, no son unicos. Los nombres de personas se repiten. Ahora volviendo a la pregunta, o sea que nada que ver lo que dice la pregunta. Vos queres saber como buscar o como guardar? Lo q pusiste en comentarios nada que ver con tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, creo que antes deberia leer un poco sobre Normalizacion en bases de datos, no es recomendable tener un nombre completo en un mismo registro.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forma_normal_(base_de_datos)

Se recomienda llegar como minimo a 3NF (Consulte el link para tener mas informacion)

Para solucionar su problema de las busquedas puede poner un Id auto incremental (Se puede hacer por medio de codigo o por gui) para que le sea mas facil darle mantenimiento y hasta le podria dar al usuario ese mismo id para que pueda ingresar a su app. 
Es mas optimo hacer busquedas por numero en comparacion a las cadenas de texto.

Este link le puede ayudar un poco para ver el tema del sql autoincrement.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: Para entender mejor la respuesta pon un ejemplo con código

Comment: Claro con gusto!

Para hacerlo por medio de GUI puedes ver este video dura un minuto.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPBq9XzfUFk

Si deseas por medio de codigo es de esta forma:

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);